# Bootstrap3 table-responsive not working if is inside container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 and to make my tables responsive use table class-responsive. I notice that if the table is inside a container, the horizontal-scrollbar is not shown correctly with mobile view.

This is my code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<div class="container">

  <p>INSIDE CONTAINER</p>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.container { width: 1000px; }
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/XHyni1eh0S)

How can fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with 
    .container { width: 1000px; }

Once parent's width is fixed, table-responsive doesn't respond to width change, as it always depends on parent's width.

You can change container's width to % so that table will become responsive.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a container of 1000px

Comment: Any reason for using fixed width for container? Once you fix it, page can't be responsive

Comment: It is very strange that it can't solve this problem in another way.

Comment: One way is to write media queries and override table-responsive's width from 100% to specific pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Because class `.container` in bootstrap setting:

```
`@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
   }
 }

 @media (min-width: 992px){
  .container {
    width: 970px;
   }
 }

 @media (min-width: 768px){
 .container {
   width: 750px;
   }
 }`
```

if you set `.container { width: 1000px; }` it will fixed and not responsive.
=>You can edit:
+Not setting class `.container`, you will setting new class `.box{width:1000px}`
+Code `<div class="box"></div>` wrap code of you.
=>Table of you will inside box width 1000px and responsive

Comment: would be awesome, but unfortunately your solution does not work,  http://www.bootply.com/kTGMBCKBgg